# matlab plotting multiple graphs and adding a straight line

Tags: matlab, plot, graph

I am trying to plot multiple graphs, and I want to add a straight line of y = 2.3 into the graph but it only shows my first two plots which are x1,OA and x2,OF.

here is my code

```
x1 = [0:1:101];
OA = 0.00022494*x1.^2;
x2 = [0:1:74.4];
OF = -0.00018056*x2.^2;
x3 = [101:1:265];
AC = 2.3;
plot(x1,OA,'r',x2,OF,'r',x3,AC,'r')
```

Comment: Instead of deleting the question after you've received an answer, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

You need to make `AC` the same size as `x3`:

```
AC = 2.3 * ones(size(x3));
```

Aside: a clearer way to do multiple plots is with `hold on`

```
figure;
hold on
plot( x1, OA, 'r' );
plot( x2, OF, 'r' );
plot( x3, AC, 'r' );
hold off
```